# open Pop up in html page

Tags: javascript, html

In my html page i am using a function to open a pop up window

```
 window.clickOnPDpopup = function(mode,prptName,prptParameters,popup_height,popup_width) {
    var url = '';
    drillurl = PRPT_URL(mode,solution,path,prptName);
    if(prptParameters == '') {
     url = drillurl+buildParameterString(KeyArray,ValueArray,DefaultValueArray);
    } else {
     url = drillurl+prptParameters;
    }
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height='+popup_height+',width='+popup_width+',left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,titlebar=0, status=no');
 }
```

`window.open`, the function i am using, opens a new window with a title bar, menu bar, status bar,...

I dont need it to show any bars. I just need it to show a `div` and inside my content, i needlose show a close button to close that window.

Please help me

Comment: make use of existing dialog box plugins written in javascript/jQuery. Here is the jQuery dialog jqueryui.com/dialog

Comment: see more about `window.open` here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) and here [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just create html page then user this:

window.open("html url",null,
"height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");

then on that html you do whatever design you want and also send data there or anything